# Inline images are lost when copying them to a RDP session

Tags: windows, remote-desktop

Observed behavior:

- Copy some text including an embedded image from an email in Outlook to the clipboard
- Paste the clipboard content to a RDP session into Word
- the text is pasted, the image itself is not visible, instead an empty box appears where the image should appear
- if I copy the image separately, so it is the only object being copied it actually works

I tried to figure out what went wrong, however most RDP problems refer to the Clipboard not working at all. Recommendations are to enable the clipboard (check) and to restart `rdpclip.exe` - which I did not expecting to resolve the problem.

**Update**

Even more surprising is the fact that some applications understand the clipboard, others do not. So I started to read the clipboard data using a simple c# program. The issue seems to be that the clipboard is filled with several formats: Text, RTF, HTML and others.

Non surprisingly text format does not contain image data. HTML however contains a file link to a local resource - which does not exist (nor is it accessible) from the remote desktop.

So what happens is that some applications read the HTML (apparently MS Word does) and insert a broken image. Others however read the RTF (WordPad for instance) which seems to come with the raw image data, so it can be inserted.

Now the question changes to: "Can I tell an application like Word to use another clipboard format?" I can imagine this is possible via other tools or plugins, but maybe someone knows a *native* solution.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, did you solved it? Would you mind to share your finding?

Comment: Not yet - I fear that it is impossible to solve unless one of the applications can be instructed to chose one of the working formats over the problematic ones - if there is a format available which it can interpret anyway. (Or have a tool which manipulates the clipboard when something is copied containing such HTML)